# Initialize ActiveRecord model by passing database url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i know that active record rails can have multiple connection to be specified in model. we can do something like this right?

```ruby
class Car < ApplicationRecord
 establish_connection("url_to_database")
end
```

but how to pass the url when initialize the model dynamically?
is it possible to do something like this below?

```ruby
Car.new(url: url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Car.establish_connection(url)
```

Please note that this database connection is per model not per instance of that model.

See [`ConnectionHandling#establish_connection`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection)

Comment: i got error `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter` is this because i use string instead of symbol?

Comment: my bad, string is not correct, sorry, lemme try again